# Increment an int stored in a generic type

Tags: java, generics, increment

If I have an int stored in a generic type, say V, what is the best way to increment that value? For example, the code below will obviously not work.

```
V v = q.value++;
```

I was thinking about extracting that value and converting it to an int, incrementing, and then storing it again as generic, but I feel like there must be an better way to do it. So my question is, is there a better way or was my original idea correct?

Cheers!

edit:

```
Storage<K, V> q = tab[index];
    while (q != null) {
        if (q.key.equals(key)) {
            K k = q.key;
            V v = q.value;
            return v;
        } else {
            q = q.next;
        }
    }
```

The value is storing how many times an identical key is being added to a hashtable.

Comment: How to use your class depends on what your class look like. We don't have any idea.

Comment: The better way is to make it an `int` if it can be an `int`  This will be faster and simpler.

Comment: Most likely, this isn't a "generics" question and is an "interfaces" question.

Comment: If it's generic how do you know it's an integer and can be incremented at all? If you know it's an integer, why use generics? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use an interface such that:

```
Storage<K extends IHasKeys, V extends IHasValues> 
q = tab[index];
    while (q != null) {
        if (q.getKey().equals(key)) {
            K k = q.getKey();
            V v = q.getValue();
            return v;
        ...
    }
```

Where the `IHasKeys` Interface declares `getKey`() and `IHasValues` declares `getValue()` methods ...